# Remote Desktop on VPS : how to keep connection alive?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, vps, windows-server-2003

I have a Windows 2003 VPS running a lot of processes. Most of them works well even if nobody is logged on, but there are some processes that simules keyboard presses that only works when i'm logged on. Is there a way to keep this behaviour even if i'm not logged on the RDM ?

Thanks

Comment: What are you using to simulate the keyboard keystroke - AutoIT or some other tool? Is the VM setup with Virtual Box, Hyper-V, or how?

Comment: I don't know where the VM is because i just paid a VPS. The keystroke is generated by an application using common Windows APIs.